# Button In UserForm does not reset after message box is closed

Tags: vba, excel

This is my first post so excuse me if I am not par on rules of submitting questions.

I have a particular problem with the button in a User Form not getting reset to its state up (or off if that's what it's called) position. I load a form that has two lists in it - one for year and the other for month.

These lists are pre populated from a sheet. When a user clicks OK, I want to be sure that each of the list box has something selected in it. If not, the rest of the processing in my code cannot take place. I check both lists on the implementation of OK button click (checking if values are null). If any of the lists are missing entries, a simple message box with OK button is shown to warn the user.

This is where the problem is. After I OK the message box and dismiss it, the OK button on the userform still is in the pressed state. [Ok Button Not Reset image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JfdW2.gif)

I tried to repaint the form. I can't seem to find a repaint option for the button itself. The button still works even though it's in the pressed state. It's just that it becomes confusing to a user to see a button that is already in the pressed state. How do I fix this issue?

Here's the (test) code of the form:

```
Private Sub LoadData_Cancel_Btn_Click()
    Unload Me
End Sub

Private Sub LoadData_OK_Btn_Click()
    Dim iReturn As Integer

    If (IsNull(List_Year.Value) Or IsNull(List_Month.Value)) Then
        MsgBox "Incomplete"
        Me.Repaint
        Exit Sub
    End If

    MsgBox List_Year.Value
    MsgBox List_Month.Value

    Unload Me
End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    List_Year.Clear
    List_Month.Clear

    With List_Year
        .AddItem "Test1"
    End With

    With List_Month
        .AddItem "Test1"
        .AddItem "Test2"
        .AddItem "Test3"
        .AddItem "Test4"
        .AddItem "Test5"
        .AddItem "Test6"
        .AddItem "Test7"
        .AddItem "Test8"
        .AddItem "Test9"
        .AddItem "Test10"
        .AddItem "Test11"
        .AddItem "Test12"
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem.  Try using if/else to eliminate the use of "Exit Sub".

Comment: Is it possible you used a toggle button on your form (instead of a command button)?

Comment: Same here, can't reproduce your issue. All working fine.

Comment: It clearly seems that, just as Jochen states, you used a toggle button not a command button. Could you verify this?

Comment: go to VBE, in the userform's design, clic the "button", and look in its properties. a button would come back to raised (at run time). also try showing the Form in vbmodless state (`Userform1.show false`), because in the other case forms wouldn't allow interaction with excel until it is closed. or even better, in the userform's properties, set showmodal to false.

Comment: Thank you all for the correction. It was a really dumb rookie error on my part. I used a Toggle button instead of the Command button.